# Javascript - Update value outside of loop and then use new value

Tags: javascript, json

I am creating a function which uses an array to navigate through a JSON object, pushing its keys to a results array at each step. The trouble is, I can't get the loop to use the updated object with each successive loop.

JSON object:

```
myData = {
    'Eye': {
        'Abnormal Morphology': [
            'Neoplasm',
            'Abnormality of the globe'
        ],
        'Abnormal Physiology': [
            'Hemorrhage',
            'Ptosis',
            'Ocular pain'
        ]
    },
    'Ear': {
        'Outer Ear': [
            'Abnormality of the pinna',
            'Abnormal location of ear',
            'Extra chondra fold'
        ],
        'Middle Ear': [
            'Glue ear',
            'Otitis media'
        ]
    }
}
```

And the function:

```
view = ['Ear', 'Outer Ear']

getMenuItems(object, array) {
    let menuItems = Object.keys(object);
    let result = [menuItems];

    for (let item in array) {
        object = object[item];         // use updated object each time
        menuItems = Object.keys(object);
        result.push(menuItems);
    }

    return result;
}
```

The result I'm expecting is:

```
[['Eye', 'Ear'], ['Outer Ear', 'Inner Ear'], ['Abnormality of the pinna', 'Abnormal location of ear', 'Extra chondra fold']]
```

But all I get is:

```
['Eye', 'Ear']
```

Comment: Maybe replace *obj* with *object* ??

Comment: Sorry changed the variable name to make it clearer and forgot that one!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what result you expect. Can you give an exemple of what result you expect ? (e.g. result should be ['foo','bar'])

Comment: Updated, sorry about that

Comment: What do you want to update, the keys or the values?

Answer (score 1):

```
for( let item in array )
```

Iterates over the items key (0,1,2). May use *of* instead to iterate over props:

```
for( const item of array )
```

Then it [works](http://jsbin.com/zefenecevo/edit?console)

Comment: Thanks, of was exactly what I needed!